# He has very good command in/over/of English

Tags: prepositions

He has very good command **in/of/over** English.

Which is the best option out of the three and why?

Comment: "Command over" means "authority over" and "Command of" means "mastery of"

Comment: W e l l . . . *command of* may have both meanings: *He was appointed to command of the Fourth Division*.

Answer (score 10):

*He has a very good [command of](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/command_1) English*. See definition 4 in the link, which says:

> **command of something** *knowledge of something, especially a language, or ability to use something*

I cannot explain why it is so. *Command over* sounds quite sensible, doesn't it? But people say *command of English, command of the situation, command of a ship, command of a squadron*, and even *command of oneself*.

You can also say **command in something**, but it doesn’t mean **command of something**. For instance you will find [here](http://www.gettyimages.pt/detail/fotografia-de-not%C3%ADcias/general-charles-mangin-french-army-officer-who-fotografia-de-not%C3%ADcias/113489350) that

> (1) General Charles Mangin had command in the First World War.

Obviously he could not have command of (control of) the whole war. We find in Wikipedia that he had command of various military units, and eventually [he had **command of** the French (or maybe Allied) 10th Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Mangin#First_World_War) only. So we could say:

> (2) General Charles Mangin had **command of** the 10th Army **in** the First World War.

But in (1) we omitted “of the 10th Army”, focussing on the **place/field/circumstances** in which he had **command of something** rather than the *something* he had command of.

Comment: Is it good command of, or a good command of?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with *he has good command*, but *he has **a** good command* sounds more natural to me.  [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+good+command+of%2Chas+a+good+command+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20good%20command%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20a%20good%20command%20of%3B%2Cc0) concurs.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably say, "He has a very good command **of the English Language.**"

Unless there was some other context in a paragraph, English is often used as an adjective so it pays to be more precise.

We could also say:

- > He has command over the English Navy
- > He has command in the English class

Comment: It didn't even cross my mind that _English_ in that sentence might mean anything other than _the English language_. Does _he has command in the English class_ necessarily mean _he has command of the English class_, or could it be interpreted as _he has command of something else, say the lighting, in the English class_?

Comment: Without anything following the word _English_ in the sentence, though, _English_ wouldn't be an adjective – it would be a noun, and refer to the language. I don't disagree with your sentiment about how it often pays to be precise, and your rewording is excellent. However, I also think it's worth mentioning that, in this case, _He has a very good command of English_ is unlikely to be regarded as confusing and ambiguous.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/English lists several different meanings for English as a noun, and only one of them is the language. While the language might be the most expected usage in the current context,  English is also a class or subject in school, the spin put onto a cue ball in pool, or a group of people. The choice of preposition will be affected by the noun chosen.

Comment: Prepositions are one of the hardest things to learn in a foreign language, as usually there isn’t a unique two-way correspondence between prepositions in two languages. For instance the French preposition **à** may, depending on context, translate as **at, by, in, of, on**, or **to**. So it really would help if you clarified whether *command in the English class* means the same as *command of the English class*, especially as the question specifically asks about the choice between **command in** and **command of**.

Answer (score -1):

Having command 'over'good English is bad English. Having command 'of' good English is correct English. Besides no one can claim to know EVERYTHING in English.